# How do I subset a data frame in R using specific row indicies?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a large data frame which I would like to break down into smaller data frames. I know which rows I would like to split up (i.e I want to separate rows 1 - 33, 34 - 60, ....). I know I have to use subset(), but I cant seem to find the specific parameters.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff - try reading through an R tutorial to get your fundamentals down.  [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/) is a good one; [here's the page for this specific question](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean from the 1st to the 33th row, just do this

```
df[1:33,]
```

as an example:

```
> df<-data.frame(A=LETTERS[1:10], B=c(1:10))
> df
   A  B
1  A  1
2  B  2
3  C  3
4  D  4
5  E  5
6  F  6
7  G  7
8  H  8
9  I  9
10 J 10

> df[1:3,]
  A B
1 A 1
2 B 2
3 C 3
```